# Confusing query_string search results

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got Elasticsearch set up and am running queries against it, but I'm getting odd results, and can't figure out why:

For example, the here's one relevant portion of my mapping:

```
"classification": {
    "type": "string",
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        }
    }
},
```

And, then here's some of the queries and results. For all of these, there are objects with classification value of "Jewelry & Adornment":

Query:

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "(classification:/jewel.*/)"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Result:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 2541,
    "max_score": 1.4142135,
    "hits": [
      {
          ...
```

Yet if I add "ry":

Query:

```
"query_string": {
    "query": "(classification:/jewelry.*/)"
}
```

Result:

```
"hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
```

I've also tried running the queries:

```
"query_string": {
    "query": "(classification\\*:/jewelry.*/)"
}
```

(should match either "classification" or "classification.raw")

And:

```
"query_string": {
    "query": "(classification.raw:/jewelry.*/)"
}
```

I've also tried cases variations, e.g. "Jewelry" vs. "jewelry", to no effect. All of these return no results. This makes no sense to me. Even when querying "classification.raw" with "Jewelry" (same case and on a completely unanalyzed field), I get no results. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

As per request of @keety

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "jewelri",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "adorn",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 19,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

I imagine the fact that it's stemming "jewelry" to "jewelri" is my problem, but not sure why it's doing that or how to fix it.

**UPDATE #2**

These are the analyzers in play:

```
"analyzer": {
    "default_index": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
        "filter": [
            "icu_folding",
            "custom_stem",
            "porter_stem",
            "index_filter"
        ],
        "char_filter": [
            "html_strip",
            "quotes"
        ]
    },
    "default_search": {
        "type": "custom",
        "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer",
        "filter": [
            "icu_folding",
            "custom_stem",
            "porter_stem",
            "search_filter"
        ],
        "char_filter": [
            "html_strip",
            "quotes"
        ]
    }
}
```

**UPDATE #3**

I ran an `_explain` query on one of the objects that should be matching but isn't and got the following:

```
"matched": false,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 0,
    "description": "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 0.70710677,
        "description": "ConstantScore(*:*), product of:",
        "details": [
          {
            "value": 1,
            "description": "boost"
          },
          {
            "value": 0.70710677,
            "description": "queryNorm"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "value": 0,
        "description": "no match on required clause (ConstantScore())"
      }
    ]
  }
```

I don't know what "required clause (ConstantScore())" is. The only thing I can find related is [Constant Score Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-constant-score-query.html), but I'm not employing this particular query anywhere.

**UPDATE #4**

Okay, this is getting a little long-winded. Sorry about that. However, I just discovered that the problem seems to lie in using the regex syntax. If I just use a basic wildcard (along with `"analyze_wildcard": true`), then all my queries start working.

Comment: can you post the result of `GET <index_name>/_analyze?fields=classification&text=Jewelry & Adornment` to get an idea how it is being analyzed

Comment: @keety: FWIW, I did try `lowercase_expanded:false` to no effect. Analyzers have been added to the question above.

Comment: I believe for the `raw` case it makes sense why there is not a match since regexp /wildcards always lowercase the query terms. Use [`lowercase_expanded:false`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) to prevent this however for `classification` it looks like it is using the  [default analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html#default-analyzers) could you check from `index settings` if there is a default anlayzer with stemming set on the index

Comment: sorry i did not see the update properly the default_search uses stemming but wildcard queries are not analyzed so `jewelry` would not match `jewelri` however for the `classification.raw` it should match with lowercase_expaned false and passing a query `Jewelry.*` case is important

Comment: My understanding was that regex queries don't apply to the rule about wildcard queries not being analyzed, as there's no way to run a regex without processing the whole thing. Regardless, I did actually try `"analyze_wildcards": true`, but that was also unsuccessful.

Comment: the constant score part has got to do with how the  wildcard query is [rewritten](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-term-rewrite.html) .

Comment: It is strange i'm able to get it to match on `classification.raw` example : [gist](https://gist.github.com/keety/a2b948976d6dfadf310c)

Comment: also if you use `"analyze_wildcards":true` make sure the query does is not a regex i.e `classification:jewelry*`

Comment: Okay. So I was able to get `classification.raw:/Jewelry.*/` to match with `lowercase_expanded_terms` true. Apparently, I was testing with "jewelry" instead of "Jewelry". However, that's not something I can really to push down to the user, so any ideas how I can fix it so the case-sensitivity is not a problem in the first place?